# How to check if cursor is inside a rectangle c#

Tags: c#

I search for checking if cursor positions is inside Rectangle bounds. I see Microsoft documentation for get bounds of the rectangle and see if the cursor is inside but every here i click out of the rectangle it work. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t27w02(v=vs.110).aspx

I searched and see there probably an anwser to my question but it seem very difficult i don't understand how the function "nearest(parameters..)" can help me by getting if yes or no i'm in the rectangle. [How to detect if my mouse position is within a rectangle c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662584/how-to-detect-if-my-mouse-position-is-within-a-rectangle-c)

Here my best i created for now:

```
    private void Log_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       if (Screen.GetBounds(new Rectangle(500, 80, 50, 50)).Contains(e.Location))
          {
             Console.WriteLine("Hi");
          }
    }
```

Comment: The `Location` will be in client coords relative to the upper-left of the control. What coordinate system is your `Rectangle` using? Is it also relative to the upper-left of the control? If so, you just need to do `if (new Rectangle(500, 80, 50, 50).Contains(e.Location))`

Comment: I already try `if (new Rectangle(500, 80, 50, 50).Contains(e.Location))`(he don't do anything)

Comment: Well what coordinate system are you using? In client coords `Rectangle(500, 80, 50, 50)` would be 500 pixels from the left of the control and 80 pixels from the top, with a width and height of 50. Is that what you want?

Comment: yeah like new Point(500, 80), width, height and when i'm into the rectangle & mouse down i WriteLine('Hi");

Answer (score 0):

No one answering question and everyone is lost with this so i post this temporarily. (The function is not optimized).

```
    private int pointX = 0;
    private int pointY = 0;

    private Boolean isInRect(Rectangle rect, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < rect.Width; i++)
        {
            if((rect.X + i) == e.X)
                pointX = rect.X + i;
        }
        for(int i=0; i < rect.Height; i++)
        {
            if ((rect.Y + i) == e.Y)
                pointY = rect.Y + i;
        }

        if (pointX != 0 && pointY != 0)
            return true;

        pointX = 0;
        pointY = 0;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).